# Bash logic to check memory and server load before launching a bacground process

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to implement the following pseudo-algorithm:

```
while true
do
  if there is 1G of free memory && server load below 60%
    ./some-script &
    break
  else
    sleep 10
  fi
done
```

I need help (advise, implementation notes on) with implementing:

1. check on if there is 1G of free memory
2. check on if the server load is less than 60%

Comment: Your script could happen to never be run, because in Linux there is no free RAM shortly after system startup, it tries to use all for buffers and cache. See http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ - check the `nice` command how to start a command with low priority. And the `renice` command lets you adjust it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a comparison against the free RAM, so we'll get that detail from /proc/meminfo.

Express load as a percentage by doing some sorcery (stolen outright from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229692/1287561)

```
while true
do
  if [ `cat /proc/meminfo |grep MemFree|awk '{ print $2 }'` -lt 1048576 && `top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | \
       sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%\id.*/\1/" | \
       awk '{print 100 - $1}'` -lt 60 ]
    ./some-script &
    break
  else
    sleep 10
  fi
done
```

Comment: What shell are you using? `<` isn't a portable operator for numbers, use `-lt` instead.

Comment: @scai You're absolutely right, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `batch(1)`, part of the `at` package. It runs the argument when load is low.